# Expo-AV Sound.playAsync() doesn't work with expo-av 9.2.3 and Expo 42.0.3

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-av

#### Summary

Context: I'm trying to make a timer app with React Native, Expo, and Expo-AV.

I'm initialising a **stock app with Managed workflow and trying to play an mp3 file** using `expo-av (9.2.3)`. I saw [another issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/13623) where no sound was playing on Moto G5, Android 8. For me, **sound doesn't play for Moto G6 Android 9, iPhone SE iOS 14.6, OR on the web.** `App.json` and `package.json` attached.

[image: app json]
[image: package json]

#### Managed or bare workflow?

managed

#### What platform(s) does this occur on?

Android, Web

#### SDK Version (managed workflow only)

42.0.3

#### Environment

Expo CLI 4.9.0 environment info:

- System:
  OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
- Binaries:
  Node: 14.17.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE,
  npm: 6.14.14 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
- IDEs:
  Android Studio: Version     2020.3.0.0 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922
- npmPackages:

  - expo: ~42.0.1 => 42.0.3
  - react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
  - react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
  - react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz => 0.63.2
  - react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18
- Expo Workflow: managed

#### Reproducible demo or steps to reproduce from a blank project

1. Run `expo init my-app`
2. Run `expo install expo-av`
3. Add some mp3 file to the root directory. I'm using [this one](https://sndup.net/2bjt).
4. Copy this code into `app.js`

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    playSound()
  }, []);

  async function playSound() {
    const sound = new Audio.Sound();
    try {
      await sound.loadAsync(require('./sound.mp3'));
      await sound.playAsync();
      await sound.unloadAsync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

5. Run `expo start`
6. Preview on Expo Go app on Moto G6 Android 9.0, iPhone SE iOS 14.6. Or open on web by entering `w` with terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a suggestion on how to change the functions I use to play the audio in the [Expo Github Issues](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/14291#issuecomment-1082551977).

Before, my code was:

```
async function playSound() {
    const sound = new Audio.Sound();
    try {
      await sound.loadAsync(require('./sound.mp3'));
      await sound.playAsync();
      await sound.unloadAsync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
}
```

Now, I used the `.setPositionAsync()` and `.playAsync()` functions, as well as the `{ shouldPlay: true}` flag. **This code worked after I updated to `"expo": "^45.0.8"` and `"expo-av": "~11.2.3"` as well** (since Expo 42 is deprecated). I haven't tested this on versions of Expo besides 42 and 45.

```
async function playSound() {
    const sound = new Audio.Sound();
    try {
      await sound.loadAsync(require('./sound.mp3'), {shouldPlay: true});
      await sound.setPositionAsync(0);
      await sound.playAsync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
}
```